# Image Uploading to a folder in classic ASP

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I am trying to upload a image into a folder using classic asp. I am able to upload image into a folder but not getting the values of other input fields.

```
<%@ Language="VBScript" %>
<!--<span class="code-comment"> #include file="vbsUpload.asp" </span>-->
<form method=post
  enctype="multipart/form-data"
  action=<%=request.servervariables("script_name")%>>
Your File:<BR><input type="file" name="YourFile"><BR>
<input type="text" name="myname" id="name12"> 
<BR>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
<% Dim objUpload, lngLoop, cia
If Request.TotalBytes > 0 Then
Set objUpload = New vbsUpload

For lngLoop = 0 to objUpload.Files.Count - 1
'If accessing this page annonymously,
'the internet guest account must have
'write permission to the path below.
objUpload.Files.Item(lngLoop).Save "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\puntoseguro\admin\image\"

Response.Write "File Uploaded"

Next
 cia = Upload.Form("myname")

End if
%>
```

When I submit the form, I am getting the following error,
File Uploaded
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8'

```
Object required: ''

/admin/test.asp, line 26

line 26 -   cia = Upload.Form("myname")
```

Comment: You wont be able to natively read the form fields and the image upload.  A work around is to use an upload component, or a script such as this one.

http://www.motobit.com/help/scptutl/pure-asp-upload.htm


Another option is to place your uploads into iframes, and use some javscript to start uploading when the file field changes.   Or, use ajax uploads which would be a more elegant way of handling all of it.

Comment: @Frank, objUpload appears to refer to one of the pure ASP upload scripts, so looks like something is already in place to accommodate uploads.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems with your code.

1) You are declaring the text box like this:

```
<input type="text" name="myname" id="name12">
```

But you are trying to get it's value using the ID (name12), but you you need to get it using it's "name" (myname).

2) Also, you should be using `objUpload.Form` instead of `Upload.Form` as `Upload` doesn't appear to exist, hence the error.

You can fix both problems by replacing this line...

```
cia = Upload.Form("name12")
```

...with...

```
cia = objUpload.Form("myname")
```

(or change the name to match the ID)

Comment: still it is not working showing the error  Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01b6'

Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: Which line is the error on? Why is `<!--<span class="code-comment"> #include file="vbsUpload.asp" </span>--> `commented out - is there another include not shown in your code (have you tried uncommenting it)?